# Finding a connecting line between two lines in 3D space, with specific requirements for its length.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given, in 3D space: a point $P$ and a direction $v$, a point $Q$ and a direction $w$. So, two lines, $L_1 = P + tv$, $L_2 = Q + tw$.

I am looking for two points, one on each line, say P' and Q'. My requirement is that the distance from $P$ to $P'$ plus $Q$ to $Q'$ equals the distance from $P'$ to $Q'$:

$$||P-P'|| + ||Q-Q'|| = ||P'-Q'||$$

Any suggestions on how to solve this? I have some experience with linear algebra, but it is rusty. My end goal is a function into which I can feed the coordinates of the two points and the two direction vectors and have it return the solution(s) t.

UPDATE: I have changed the parameter for the line equations, they now both use the same parameter instead of separate ones. I hope this will make it solvable...

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Regards

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and formatting! I hope my question is clear enough now...

Comment: You have one equation in two variables, so the solution is generally not unique. For example, if you fix $t=0$, you get $\lVert P-P'\rVert+0=\lVert P'-Q\rVert$, that is, $P'$ is the point where $L_1$ intersects the bisecting plane between $P$ and $Q$. You get another solution similarly by fixing $s=0$, and probably lots of other solutions in between.

Comment: @RahulNarain Doesn't the fact that P' and Q' are on the given lines count as two extra equations?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. Let $P'=P+sv$ and $Q'=Q+tw$, so that $P'$ and $Q'$ are automatically on the given lines. Then you have two scalar variables $s$ and $t$, and one scalar equation $\lVert sv\rVert+\lVert tw\rVert=\lVert P+sv-Q-tw\rVert$.

Comment: @RahulNarain I was afraid of that... But would it help if we added this equation: $s=t$? Seems a bit silly, but it would be fine for my application, if it then always has a solution (except maybe for cases like $P=Q$, $v=-w$ which can be caught in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PART - 2**

I keep the notation as above. To wit, $P,Q$ are the fixed points on $L_1,L_2$. The vectors $v,w$ are the direction vector along $L_1,L_2$ and $P',Q'$ are the points to be found. Define two function $f,g:L_1\times L_2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ as follows :

1. $f(P',Q')= \|P'-Q'\|$
2. $g(P',Q')=\|P-P'\| + \|Q-Q'\|$

Note that $f$ has a minimum and is attained at $P_0$ and $Q_0$ as our earlier notation says. The function $g$ has minimum $0$.

We estimate these two functions for their growth characteristics. Also remember the four cases outlined in part 1. I define the condition $\|P-P_0\| + \|Q-Q_0\|\leq\|P_0-Q_0\|$ as $K$.

From **part 1** it follows that if $K$ is true then there is a solution. And it involves choosing that case which moves $P',Q'$ closer to $P_0,Q_0$. Now I will describe the solution if $K$ does not hold.

Define the function $d_1,d_2:\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ as $d_1(t)=f(P+tv,Q+tw)$ and $d_2(t)=g(P+tv,Q+tw)$. Notice that of the four cases outlined above we can study all of them by just redefining $v$ & $w$ as either positive or negative of it. So without defining too many things we can consider all the cases with the same $d_1$ & $d_2$ one by one.

1. $d_2(t)=t\|v\|+\|w\|$. this is a linear function which starts from $0$ and increases without bound with a slope of $\|v\|+\|w\|$.
2. $d_1(t)=\|P-Q + t(v-w)\| \leq \|P-Q\| + t\|v-w\|$. The growth of $d_2$ starts with a positive number, is ultimately a linear growth with a slope less than $\|v-w\|$.

Now the four cases come into play. Choosing any case is equivalent to redefining $v,w$ as either positive or negative of it. So choose that case which makes $\|v-w\|$ strictly smaller than $\|v\|+\|w\|$. Now observe the behavior of the graph of $d_1$ & $d_2$. Both of them are straight lines with different slopes and start with different values at $t=0$. So they must intersect. And that gives the solution.

Note :

1. Actually $d_2$ may not be a straight line initially but for large values of $t$, it is ultimately a straight line and hence the conclusions remain unchanged.
2. There may be more solutions which are not described by this method. One of the reasons is that we have chosen to move $P'$ and $Q'$ in tandem. If we move them independently by accepting two parameters $t$ and $s$, we may find other solutions too. But still there cud be more solutions.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I did find a solution now: starting with $t(∥v∥+∥w∥)=||P+tv-Q-tw||$ I expanded the right part to the formula for calculating the magnitude, like: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and ended up with a formula like $at^2+bt+c=0$ which can be solved with the quadratic formula. This seems to always give the solution I need, a positive t, except when $P=Q$ or $v=-w$. I know there are two $+ or -$ choices here, in getting rid of the square root and the abc-formula itself, but ignoring them works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**PART 1**

You probably want an algorithm to find the answer. I am ignoring the trivial case of parallel lines.

Consider the points $P'$ and $Q'$ as moving points along their respective lines. Now consider the four possible cases -

1. $P'$ moves in $+v$ direction, $Q'$ moves in $+w$ direction.
2. $P'$ moves in $+v$ direction, $Q'$ moves in $-w$ direction.
3. $P'$ moves in $-v$ direction, $Q'$ moves in $+w$ direction.
4. $P'$ moves in $-v$ direction, $Q'$ moves in $-w$ direction.

In all the cases if you move very far, the distance between $P'$ and $Q'$ will ultimately start increasing. Remember the lines are not parallel. But in some of the cases the distance may first decrease and then increase. Choose the case of decreasing distance.

Now find out the minimum distance between these two lines. Say this minimum is attained at $P_0$ and $Q_0$. Clearly among the four cases outlined above whichever case moves $P'$ closer to $P_0$ and $Q'$ closer to $Q_0$ is the case we have chosen.

Suppose $\|P-P_0\| + \|Q-Q_0\|\leq\|P_0-Q_0\|$, then there must exist a solution because the sum $\|P-P'\| + \|Q-Q'\|$ start with $0$ and increases whereas $\|P'-Q'\|$ starts with $\|P-Q\|$ and decreases to $\|P_0-Q_0\|$ as you start moving the points. [Note that initially $P'=P$ and $Q'=Q$].

To find this solution you just have to move $P'$ from $P$ to $P_0$ and $Q'$ from $Q$ to $Q_0$. Somewhere you will find it.

However if $\|P-P_0\| + \|Q-Q_0\|\leq\|P_0-Q_0\|$ does not hold, then this algorithm will not work. I will try those cases presently and get back.

Comment: to find $P_0$ and $Q_0$ please note that this is a two variable optimization problem where you have to find the minimum of $f(s,t)=\|P-Q+tv-sw\|$ and the corresponding value of $s$ and $t$.

Comment: thanks for your help! as you can see in my responses to the original post I have added an equation (or technically removed a variable) by setting $s=t$. Also I might note that I'm only interested in positive directions for $v$ and $w$.

Comment: specifying only positive direction of the vectors is meaningless as negative of the vector describes the same line. I think a more meaningful question is to describe the lines as $L1=P\pm tv, L2=Q\pm tw$ and then ask for $t$ such that your condition is met. but even if you put this condition, nothing much is changed ... the above cases and condition for solution remains unaltered.

Comment: Let me work out the other cases now. Suppose the condition I mentioned $\|P-P_0\| + \|Q-Q_0\|\leq\|P_0-Q_0\|$ does not hold. Then clearly both the sum $\|P-P'\| + \|Q-Q'\|$ and the distance $\|P'-Q'\|$ will have to keep in increasing and so we must ask whether these two increasing functions of $P'$ and $Q'$ ever take the same value.

Comment: To find out we must analyze the growth characteristics of these two functions. And for simplicity I will use your later restriction $s=t$ but the conclusions remain unchanged.

Observe that $\|P-P'\| + \|Q-Q'\| = |t|(\|v\|+\|w\|)$ which grows linearly with some slope.

The function $\|P'-Q'\| \leq \|P-Q\| + |t|(\|v\|+\|w\|)$ so it's growth is "atmost" linear with the same slope.

So these two functions will never catch up with each other. 

It follows that the sufficient condition I derived $\|P-P_0\| + \|Q-Q_0\|\leq\|P_0-Q_0\|$ is also necessary for the solution.

Comment: The above comment is not very accurate. I have realized that solution exists in all cases. My previous answer is correct ... I will expand that as part 2 in a new answer. give me some time.

Comment: Great! I'm looking forward to it. By the way, what I meant by "positive directions for $v$ and $w$" was that I'm looking for a positive value of $t$.